# C++ scanner.h scan content between double-quotes as a token: not skipping spaces inside quotes

Tags: c++, string, class, token, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to get the content between a double-quote to count as one token for an assignment.

For example: 
"hello world" = 1 token
"hello" "world" = 3 tokens (because space counts as 1 token)

I created main.cpp and I added "scanQuotesAsString" code to 3 modules given:

- scanner.cpp
- scanner.h
- scanpriv.h

Right now, "hello world" scans a 2 tokens, not skipping the space. If I add (or skipspace, then regular input such as |hello world| without quotes skips spaces as well.

I think my issue is in scanner.cpp, where the last couple functions are:

```
/*
* Private method: scanToEndOfIdentifier
* Usage: finish = scanToEndOfIdentifier();
* ----------------------------------------
* This function advances the position of the scanner until it
* reaches the end of a sequence of letters or digits that make
* up an identifier. The return value is the index of the last
* character in the identifier; the value of the stored index
* cp is the first character after that.
*/
int Scanner::scanToEndOfIdentifier() {
    while (cp < len && isalnum(buffer[cp])) {
        if ((stringOption == ScanQuotesAsStrings) && (buffer[cp] == '"')) 
            break;
        cp++;
    }
    return cp - 1;
}


/* Private functions */
/*
* Private method: scanQuotedString
* Usage: scanQuotedString();
* -------------------
* This function advances the position of the scanner until the
* current character is a double quotation mark
*/
void Scanner::scanQuotedString() {
    while ((cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"')) || (cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"'))){
        cp++;
    }
```

**Here is main.cc**

```
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "scanner.h"
#include <iostream>

/* Private function prototypes */

int CountTokens(string str);

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter a sentence: ";
    string str = GetLine();

    int num = CountTokens(str);
    cout << "You entered " << num << " tokens." << endl;
    return 0;
}

int CountTokens(string str) {

    int count = 0;
    Scanner scanner;        // create new scanner object            
    scanner.setInput(str);  // initialize the input to be scanned

    //scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::PreserveSpaces);
    scanner.setStringOption(Scanner::ScanQuotesAsStrings);

    while (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) { // read tokens from the scanner
        scanner.nextToken();
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

**Here's scanner.cpp**

```
/*
* File: scanner.cpp
* -----------------
* Implementation for the simplified Scanner class.
*/
#include "genlib.h"
#include "scanner.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
/*
* The details of the representation are inaccessible to the client,
* but consist of the following fields:
*
* buffer -- String passed to setInput
* len -- Length of buffer, saved for efficiency
* cp -- Current character position in the buffer
* spaceOption -- Setting of the space option extension
*/
Scanner::Scanner() {
    buffer = "";
    spaceOption = PreserveSpaces;
}
Scanner::~Scanner() {
/* Empty */
}
void Scanner::setInput(string str) {
    buffer = str;
    len = buffer.length();
    cp = 0;
}
/*
* Implementation notes: nextToken
* -------------------------------
* The code for nextToken follows from the definition of a token.
*/
string Scanner::nextToken() {
    if (cp == -1) {
        Error("setInput has not been called");
    }
    if (stringOption == ScanQuotesAsStrings) scanQuotedString();
    if (spaceOption == IgnoreSpaces) skipSpaces();
    int start = cp;
    if (start >= len) return "";
    if (isalnum(buffer[cp])) {
        int finish = scanToEndOfIdentifier();
        return buffer.substr(start, finish - start + 1);
    }
    cp++;
    return buffer.substr(start, 1);
}

bool Scanner::hasMoreTokens() {
    if (cp == -1) {
        Error("setInput has not been called");
    }
    if (stringOption == ScanQuotesAsStrings) scanQuotedString();
    if (spaceOption == IgnoreSpaces) skipSpaces();
    return (cp < len);
}

void Scanner::setSpaceOption(spaceOptionT option) {
    spaceOption = option;
}

Scanner::spaceOptionT Scanner::getSpaceOption() {
    return spaceOption;
}

void Scanner::setStringOption(stringOptionT option) {
    stringOption = option;
}

Scanner::stringOptionT Scanner::getStringOption() {
    return stringOption;
}


/* Private functions */
/*
* Private method: skipSpaces
* Usage: skipSpaces();
* -------------------
* This function advances the position of the scanner until the
* current character is not a whitespace character.
*/
void Scanner::skipSpaces() {
    while (cp < len && isspace(buffer[cp])) {
        cp++;
    }
}

    /*
    * Private method: scanToEndOfIdentifier
    * Usage: finish = scanToEndOfIdentifier();
    * ----------------------------------------
    * This function advances the position of the scanner until it
    * reaches the end of a sequence of letters or digits that make
    * up an identifier. The return value is the index of the last
    * character in the identifier; the value of the stored index
    * cp is the first character after that.
    */
    int Scanner::scanToEndOfIdentifier() {
        while (cp < len && isalnum(buffer[cp])) {
            if ((stringOption == ScanQuotesAsStrings) && (buffer[cp] == '"')) 
                break;
            cp++;
        }
        return cp - 1;
    }


    /* Private functions */
    /*
    * Private method: scanQuotedString
    * Usage: scanQuotedString();
    * -------------------
    * This function advances the position of the scanner until the
    * current character is a double quotation mark
    */
    void Scanner::scanQuotedString() {
        while ((cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"')) || (cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"'))){
            cp++;
        }
```

**scanner.h**

```
/*
* File: scanner.h
* ---------------
* This file is the interface for a class that facilitates dividing
* a string into logical units called "tokens", which are either
*
* 1. Strings of consecutive letters and digits representing words
* 2. One-character strings representing punctuation or separators
*
* To use this class, you must first create an instance of a
* Scanner object by declaring
*
* Scanner scanner;
*
* You initialize the scanner's input stream by calling
*
* scanner.setInput(str);
*
* where str is the string from which tokens should be read.
* Once you have done so, you can then retrieve the next token
* by making the following call:
*
* token = scanner.nextToken();
*
* To determine whether any tokens remain to be read, you can call
* the predicate method scanner.hasMoreTokens(). The nextToken
* method returns the empty string after the last token is read.
*
* The following code fragment serves as an idiom for processing
* each token in the string inputString:
*
* Scanner scanner;
* scanner.setInput(inputString);
* while (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) {
* string token = scanner.nextToken();
* . . . process the token . . .
* }
*
* This version of the Scanner class includes an option for skipping
* whitespace characters, which is described in the comments for the
* setSpaceOption method.
*/
#ifndef _scanner_h
#define _scanner_h
#include "genlib.h"
/*
* Class: Scanner
* --------------
* This class is used to represent a single instance of a scanner.
*/
class Scanner {
public:
/*
* Constructor: Scanner
* Usage: Scanner scanner;
* -----------------------
* The constructor initializes a new scanner object. The scanner
* starts empty, with no input to scan.
*/
    Scanner();
/*
* Destructor: ~Scanner
* Usage: usually implicit
* -----------------------
* The destructor deallocates any memory associated with this scanner.
*/
    ~Scanner();
/*
* Method: setInput
* Usage: scanner.setInput(str);
* -----------------------------
* This method configures this scanner to start extracting
* tokens from the input string str. Any previous input string is
* discarded.
*/
    void setInput(string str);
/*
* Method: nextToken
* Usage: token = scanner.nextToken();
* -----------------------------------
* This method returns the next token from this scanner. If
* nextToken is called when no tokens are available, it returns the
* empty string.
*/
    string nextToken();
/*
* Method: hasMoreTokens
* Usage: if (scanner.hasMoreTokens()) . . .
* ------------------------------------------
* This method returns true as long as there are additional
* tokens for this scanner to read.
*/
    bool hasMoreTokens();
/*
* Methods: setSpaceOption, getSpaceOption
* Usage: scanner.setSpaceOption(option);
* option = scanner.getSpaceOption();
* ------------------------------------------
* This method controls whether this scanner
* ignores whitespace characters or treats them as valid tokens.
* By default, the nextToken function treats whitespace characters,
* such as spaces and tabs, just like any other punctuation mark.
* If, however, you call
*
* scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::IgnoreSpaces);
*
* the scanner will skip over any white space before reading a
* token. You can restore the original behavior by calling
*
* scanner.setSpaceOption(Scanner::PreserveSpaces);
*
* The getSpaceOption function returns the current setting
* of this option.
*/
    enum spaceOptionT { PreserveSpaces, IgnoreSpaces };
    void setSpaceOption(spaceOptionT option);
    spaceOptionT getSpaceOption();

/*
 * Methods: setStringOption, getStringOption
 * Usage: scanner.setStringOption(option);
 *        option = scanner.getStringOption();
 * --------------------------------------------------
 * This method controls how the scanner reads double quotation marks 
 * as input.  The default is set to treat quotes just like any other 
 * punctuation character: 
 *    scanner.setStringOption(Scanner::ScanQuotesAsPunctuation);
 * 
 * Otherwise, the option:
 *    scanner.setStringOption(Scanner::ScanQuotesAsStrings);
 *
 * the token starting with a quotation mark will be scanned until
 * another quotation mark is found (closing quotation). Therefore
 * the entire string within the quotation, including both quotation
 * marks counts as 1 token.
 */
    enum stringOptionT { ScanQuotesAsPunctuation, ScanQuotesAsStrings };

    void setStringOption(stringOptionT option);
    stringOptionT getStringOption();


private:

#include "scanpriv.h"
};
#endif
```

** and finally scanpriv.h **

```
/*
* File: scanpriv.h
* ----------------
* This file contains the private data for the simplified version
* of the Scanner class.
*/

/* Instance variables */
string buffer; /* The string containing the tokens */
int len; /* The buffer length, for efficiency */
int cp; /* The current index in the buffer */
spaceOptionT spaceOption; /* Setting of the space option */
stringOptionT stringOption;

/* Private method prototypes */
void skipSpaces();
int scanToEndOfIdentifier();
void scanQuotedString();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To long to read.

Two ways of parsing quoted text:

## 0) State

A simple switch that tells whether you are in quotes right now, and which activates some special quotation handling. This would basically be equivalent to #1), just inline.

## 1) Sub-Rule in Recursive Descent Scanner

Put the state away and write a separate rule for scanning quoted text. The code would actually be quite simple (C++ inspired p-code):

```
// assume we are one behind the opening quotation mark
for (c : text) {
    if (is_escape (*c)) {  // to support stuff like "foo's name is \"bar\""
        p = peek(c);
        if (!is_valid_escape_character (peek (c))) error;
        else {
            make the peeked character (*p) part of the result;
            ++c;
        }
    }
    else if (is_quotation_mark (*c))
    {
        return the result; // we approached the end of the string
    }
    else if (!is_valid_character (*c))
    {
        error; // maybe you want to forbid literal control characters
    }
    else
    {
        make *c part of the result
    }
}
error; // reached end of input before closing quotation mark
```

If you do not want so support escape characters, the code gets simpler:

```
// assume we are one behind the opening quotation mark
for (c : text) {
    if (is_quotation_mark (*c))
        return the result;
    else if (!is_valid_character (*c))
        error;
    else
        make *c part of the result
}
error; // reached end of input before closing quotation mark
```

You should not omit the check whether its an invalid character, as this would invite users to exploit your code and possibly make use of undefined behavior of your program.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick glance over the code: If you are in `ScanQuotesAsStrings` mode, you expect no other tokens than quoted strings; rather, the difference should be that when you see a token that begins with `'"'`, you then go to a separate sub-scanner.

In pseudocode (using the C++ "end iterator is one-past-the-end" idiom):

```
current_token.begin = cursor;
current_token.end = current_token.begin + 1;
if(scan_quotes_as_strings && *current_token.begin == '"') {
    while(*current_token.end && *current_token.end != '"')
        ++current_token.end;
    return;
}
while(*current_token.end && *current_token.end != ' ')
    ++current_token.end;
```

You can combine these two loops to a single one by introducing a state variable rather than expressing the scanner state with different code paths.

Also,

```
while ((cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"')) || (cp < len && (buffer[cp] == '"'))) ...
```

just looks fishy.

Comment: I think you should check for the validness of the read characters.

Comment: Validity of the characters read is defined by the language parsed, which I don't know anything about. The requirement so far is that tokens are space delimited unless quoted; maybe his/her language uses Codepage 437 input and accepts smilies inside strings or identifiers.